# Regresar al inicio del programa después de un “case” cumplido, en c#

Tags: c#, menu, switch

¡Hola!, tengo un problema, y,  si alguien me pudiera ayudar con el  siguiente fragmento de código.
Después de que se cumplen las diferentes opciones del SWITCH, para un menu, ¿Como le hago para regresar al menu principal?.

```
namespace Correcion_arreglo_menu_clases_Poo
{
    class Menu
    {
   
        public void Aomenu_principal()
        {
            //imprime bantalla negra...
            string a = Console.ReadLine(); //para comenzar presione cualquier tecla.
            Console.Clear();

            
            Datos operador = new Datos(); //llamamos nuestra clase
            byte opcion; //variable para nestra selecion
            operador.Aomenu_01(); //imprime el mensaje de nuestra clase.
            opcion = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine()); //almacena nuestra selecion

            Operaciones sa = new Operaciones();
            Arreglo array = new Arreglo();

            do
            {
                //operador.Aop_2(); //prueba
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1: operador.Aomenu_02(); //ingresar y almacena datos..
                        break;
                    case 2: array.Empleado();
                        break;
                    case 3:array.Empleado();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("-saliiendo");
                        break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine(" No exitte el numero ingresea en nuestro parametro");
                        break;
                }        

            } while (opcion >3);

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con *regresar al menú principal*? Cual es el menú principal? Ahí solo veo un menú

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, y por mi menu principal lo tengo separado de esa clase, solo invoco los métodos para que impriman pantalla., pero, realmente te Agradezco  ya que logre solucionar  el  problema.

Answer (score 0):

PD: se que es mi duda, pero ya lo solucione, y dejo este post si alguien llega a estar en la situacion, en la que estuve.

Como yo lo solucione fue lo siguiente:

Nota: si trabajas de forma de Poo, has los tres paso, pero, si trabajas
de forma estructurada, pásate hasta el ultimo  paso.

1. mandar a llamar  tu clase donde se encuentra tu Switch hacia donde la clase
   donde quieras retornar, en pocas palabras al case.

ejemplo, en mi caso:

```
Menu ir = new Menu();    //lugar donde se encuentra el switch
```

2.Ya estando en lugar donde esta tu clase que retorne, es decir, en el case.
hasta abajo¿, ingresas la function consola, y abajo de ese, ingress un operador
(nombre que gustes) + el punto + el nombre del. Método, sin llamar al atributo del metodo (public static) o el valor que no retorna (void).

```
 Console.ReadKey();  

ir.Aomenu_principal(); //ejemplo en mi caso:
```

Espero que mi explicación te allá servido de ayuda.

Comment: dejare un ejemplo en otro comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo resuelto usando la explicación anterior.
antes de eso ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Crea una clase con el mismo nombre, llamado Datos
2. Copia y  pega todo el código en esa clase Datos
3. En la clase program, la default por normal pega lo siguiente:

   ```
   Datos operador = new Datos();

   operador.Menu();
   ```
4. Copila el prograna.

Código para copiar:

```
   namespace Solucion_case
   {
     class Datos
    { 
    

    //copia todo esto en otra clase con el nombre Datos
    // pega lo siguiente en la clase program, sin los diagonales. copia y pega
    //Datos operador = new Datos();
    //operador.Menu();

    //declaramos nuestra variables
    public string name; //variable nombre
    public string name_2; //variable apellido
    public byte opcion; //declaramos nuestra variable de decion
   
  
   
    public void Menu() // metodo
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Clear(); //limpiar pantalla
            //impresion del menu
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "1. imprimir");
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "2. -SALIR--");
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Selecione una opci{on");
            opcion = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();

                    Datos per = new Datos(); //le declaramos un operador 
                    //declaramos nuestro operador que es "Per"                         //a nuestr metodo

                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "¿Cual es su nombre?");
                    per.name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "¿Cual es su apellido?");
                    per.name_2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    string[] array_1 = { per.name, per.name_2 };
                    string[] array_2 = new string[2];

                    //intercambia informacion y lo almacena.
                    array_1.CopyTo(array_2, 0);

                    //ciclo que solo imprime....
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {

                        //(.....)  imprime los datos, pero con un error
                        //realmente no se cual es el error.
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + array_1[i]);

                    }
                    //imprime los datos por segunda ocasion
                    Console.Clear();
                    string[] base_dat = new string[10];
                    array_2.CopyTo(base_dat, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Datos ingresado");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + base_dat[0] + "\n" + base_dat[1]);

                    Console.ReadKey();
                    per.Menu();
                    

                    break;
                case 2: Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Saliendo");
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine(" No exitte el numero ingresea en nuestro parametro");
                    break;
            }
        } while (2>2);
      }
    }
  }
```

5. No olvides poner las librerias necesarias, aqui te las dejos.

   ```
     sing System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
   ```

PD: yo así les digo librerías, realmente no lo se´ si estoy bien.

Ten cuenta que esto de la explicación anterior, y espero que te alla servido de utilidad.